# Spark streaming not working

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a rudimentary spark streaming word count and its just not working.

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

sc = SparkContext(appName='streaming', master="local[*]")
scc = StreamingContext(sc, batchDuration=5)

lines = scc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9998)
words = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split())
counts = words.map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)

counts.pprint()

print 'Listening'
scc.start()
scc.awaitTermination()
```

I have on a another terminal running `nc -lk 9998` and I pasted some text. It prints out the typical logs (no exceptions) but it ends up queuing the job for some weird time (45 yrs) and it keeps on printing this...

```
15/06/19 18:53:30 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:874
15/06/19 18:53:30 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 2 (PythonRDD[7] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:43)
15/06/19 18:53:30 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 2.0 with 1 tasks
15/06/19 18:53:35 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1434754415000 ms
15/06/19 18:53:40 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1434754420000 ms
15/06/19 18:53:45 INFO JobScheduler: Added jobs for time 1434754425000 ms
...
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark Streaming requires multiple executors to work. Try using local[4] for the master.

Comment: Thanks. I thought `local[*]` would automatically allocate executors based on the locally available cores? (having said that, it solves my problem but curious to see why `*` didn't work)

Comment: It's not clear from docs but I think doing `local[*]` is similar to `local`, which creates only one thread for the receiver and no threads for the executor.